# Sum-to-one constraint

Tags: optimization, terminology

This is a general question, but I am asking it since I am not able to find any good material online. Can someone please explain what's meant by a "sum-to-one constraint"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be some context to suggest the meaning. Evidently, some things are constrained (perhaps in an optimization problem) to have a sum of $1$.

Comment: @dfeuer...thanks for the reply..so is it like an assumption that summation of a series tends to 1?

Comment: Maybe. You should see something in the text about some sum or other being $1$, and this is referring back to that.

Comment: @thanks again...that explains it...